# Why is this simpler analysis for the check associativity problem incorrect?

Tags: probability, algorithms, random

The check associativity problem is:

**Input.** A binary operator $*$ on a set $X$ of size $n$.

**Output.** "Yes" if $*$ is associative (i.e., $\forall{i, j, k \in X}, (i*j)*k = i*(j*k)$); "No" otherwise.

The randomized algorithm given below is due to [RS96].

1. Uniformly at random, pick 3 sets $R, S, T$ from the powerset $2^X$.
2. if $(R * S) * T \neq R * (S * T)$: output "No"
3. else output "Yes" (with one-sided error).

If the algorithm outputs "No", it is always correct. We want to bound the probability that the algorithm makes a mistake if $X$ is non-associative.

If $X$ is non-associative then there must exist at least one triple $i', j', k'$ such that $(i'*j')*k' \neq i'*(j'*k')$.

We want to bound the probability of the event that $X$ is non-associative but we output "Yes". Formally, we want to prove the following claim:

**Claim.** If $*$ is not associative, then at least 1/8 of the possible triples $R$, $S$, $T$ are witnesses, i.e., $$\Pr[(R * S) * T = R * (S * T)] \leq \frac{7}{8}.$$

I am writing out each claim of the analysis so it is easier to identify my mistake:

1. We make a mistake if we happen to pick triples $R$, $S$, and $T$ such that $i' \notin R$, $j' \notin S$, OR $k' \notin T$.
2. If we pick a set u.a.r. from $2^X$ then the probability that any fixed element is in that set is 1/2. (Why? This is because each element is in exactly half the sets in $2^X$.)
3. $\Pr[(R * S) * T = R * (S * T)] \leq \Pr[i' \notin R \; \lor \; j' \notin S \; \lor \; k' \notin T]$. (Inequality is because there could be other non-associative triples.)
4. Then: $$
   \begin{align}
   \Pr[i' \notin R \; \lor \; j' \notin S \; \lor \; k' \notin T] 
   &= 1 - \Pr[i' \in R, j' \in S, k' \in T] \\
   &= 1 - \Pr[i' \in R] \cdot \Pr[j' \in S] \cdot \Pr[k' \in T] \\
   &= 1 - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \\
   &= \frac{7}{8}
   \end{align}
   $$ where the second step is because $R$, $S$, and $T$ are selected independently.

The more standard analysis is given [here](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/%7Eschulman/Courses/18cs150/lec9.pdf). Can anyone please help me understand where I went wrong?

[RS96] S. Rajagopalan and L. Schulman, "Verifying identities." Proceedings of 37th IEEE Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science (FOCS), 1996, pp. 612–616.

Comment: $\frac78$ is certainly an upper bound, but I'm not convinced that it is the least upper bound. Essentially, you are assuming there can be examples with only one witness to the failure of associativity. It seems like you might be able to do better than that, but I can't find an immediate argument to get a better bound. Basically, a non-associative operator on $n$ elements might always have $f(n)$ witnesses, for some function $f.$

Comment: For example, if we define $a*b=a$ for all $(a,b)\neq (a_0,b_0)$ and pick any value $a_0*b_0=c_0\neq a_0,$ then we get $a*(b*c)\neq (a*b)*c$ when $a=a_0$ and $b=b_0.$ So there are $n$ triples as witness. It seems very hard, possibly impossible, to come up with an example which has only one witness. In this example, the probability we would not find witness $$\frac12+\frac12\frac12=\frac34.$$

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for getting back - for my purposes, a loose upper bound is fine because I'm more focused on correctness. The standard analysis achieves the same bound.

Comment: Is this algorithm supposed to be much faster than just deterministically checking all instances of the associative law?  One run of the randomized algorithm seems faster than the deterministic one by a factor $8$ on average, but you'll need to run the randomized algorithm several times to reduce the error probability.

Comment: Hi @AndreasBlass, yes! See the link in the original post, this runs in $O(n^2)$. The deterministic algorithm which evaluates each triple runs in $O(n^3)$.